# Is there a way to use container<T>::size_type universally for different types T?

Tags: c++, std

Suppose I have a class with `std::vector<bool> a` and `std::vector<int> b` fields that I want to `reserve()` in a constructor to some size which is equal for both containers. Given that `reserve()` accepts `size_type` parameter, to be fully safe, I have to - from what I understand - write my constructor using two parameters, which is not particularly appealing:

```
MyCtor(std::vector<bool>::size_type size1, std::vector<int>::size_type size2)
{
    abortIfNotEqual(size1, size2); // Proceed only if size1 == size2
    a.reserve(size1);
    b.reserve(size2);
}
```

From what I've read, `size_type` is *usually* the same as `size_t`, at least for standard containers, so I could probably do this without ever encountering any potential problems:

```
MyCtor(std::size_t size)
{
    a.reserve(size); // More readable, but is this always ok?
    b.reserve(size);
}
```

However, is there a better, safer way to strictly use `size_type` without having to access it via a specific `container<T>` for a specific type `T`?

Having to use a specific `container<T>` is also rather annoying when e.g. accessing an element: for `a[i]`, `i` has to be `std::vector<bool>::size_type`, as I assume that using e.g. `unsigned int i` would be less safe.

Is there a common, universal, more readable way to go in such situations? Or should I simply use `size_t` or even `unsigned long int` and forget about this?

Comment: I know that's not canon, but you can just use `std::int64_t` or potentially even `int` for both, which even lets you assert nicely no one produced a negative value on accident when calling the function. If you want to hear similar advice from prominent committee members: 
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything 9:50, 42:40, 1:02:50

Comment: Btw, the direct answer to your question probably would be `std::common_type`, but again, I think that's overkill.

Comment: Since `std::size_t` must be large enough to represent the maximal size of allocated memory and since all object in a vector will have a size larger than one, `std::size_t` can represent the size of any vector.

Comment: @Oliv That applies to bytes, but `std::vector<bool>` indexes bits, so that need not help.

Comment: You can use `size_t` and static assert, that it's the same as `vector<T>::size_type`. It's both safe and readable.

Comment: @Oliv, I'm not sure that "`std::size_t` must be large enough to represent the maximal size of allocated memory," though I agree that it will be if the allocated memory comes from `std::malloc`.  Rather, `std::size_t` must be large enough to store the result of `sizeof`, i.e., the size of any _object_.  If I have a blob of memory, `sizeof ptr` only returns the size of the pointer, not the blob, so I don't see why the blob couldn't be "arbitrarily" large.

Answer (score 3):

Since the primary component of your question is how do you ensure your safety while just assuming the size types are the same, I would recommend static_assert std::is_same. This compiles with c++17:

Simplifying the notation was important, so here, I typedef a size_type on this class, and internally make sure it is the same as both of the size types it is representing. If they don't match, it is a compile time error.

```
#include <vector>

class MyCtor {
    std::vector<bool> a;
    std::vector<int> b;
    typedef std::vector<bool>::size_type st1;
    typedef std::vector<int>::size_type st2;
    static_assert(std::is_same<st1, st2>::value);
public:
    typedef st2 size_type;
    MyCtor(size_type s1, size_type s2) {}
};
```

Special thanks to this stack overflow answer: [How to check if two types are same at compiletime(bonus points if it works with Boost strong typedef)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071340/how-to-check-if-two-types-are-same-at-compiletimebonus-points-if-it-works-with) which also includes the c++11 workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have the function accept the smaller of the two types.  In C++11, this can be done via:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>

typedef std::vector<bool>::size_type boolType;
typedef std::vector<int>::size_type intType;

typedef std::conditional<(std::numeric_limits<boolType>::max() <
                          std::numeric_limits<intType>::max()),
                         boolType,
                         intType>::type smallerSizeType;

MyCtor(smallerSizeType size)
{...}
```

Lacking C++11, you can manually define your own version of `std::conditional` and replace `std::numeric_limits<boolType>::max()` with `static_cast<boolType>(-1)`, etc..

Comment: Alternatively, you could accept the _larger_ of the two types and then check for overflow (before calling `reserve`) _inside_ the function.  This makes checking for overflow issues the function's responsibility rather than the caller's.

Comment: (To get the _larger_ type, `std::common_type` should suffice.)